# Load appropriate TensorFlow.js version for app or Node script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, tensorflow.js

I have a TensorFlow.js model that I want to use both in the browser and from a script run at the command line via Node. The model is defined in a CommonJS module, so I can easily load it in both environments. I am using Webpack to bundle the browser app. But I can't figure out how to load the appropriate version of TensorFlow.js. I want to use `tfjs-node` when running the script, but `tfjs` in the browser.

I tried using dynamic import to load the right module at runtime, but this forces me to use a CDN for `tfjs`, since it'll be loading it in the browser. What I want to do is build my app using `tfjs`, but `require` the model into an independent Node script, and use `tfjs-node` in that context. This must be a reasonably common scenario, but I cannot see a way to do it. What am I missing?

**Edit**: I'm thinking maybe I can achieve this by bundling for both the browser and node? That's possible using the `target` property in `webpack.config.js`. It's possible to specify [multiple targets](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#multiple-targets). But how to set the version of TensorFlow.js for each target? Possibly by [aliasing](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) the relevant package within each target config? So I would just use the same alias, but it would map to `tfjs` for the browser target config, and `tfjs-node` in the Node target config.

Comment: Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I eventually found a satisfactory way to achieve this using environment variables.

It's possible to pass environment variables to Webpack and access them during the compilation process, so their values can be substituted into your code. We need to modify `webpack.config.js` to do this, in the following way:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
      publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "process.env.TFJS": JSON.stringify(`${env.TFJS}`) })
    ]
  }
};
```

We need to define the exported config object as a function, so any environment variables passed via the command line are accessible via the `env` argument. Then we use Webpack's `DefinePlugin` to make the environment variables available in our code at compile time. Here we are exposing the variable `TFJS`, passed via the command line in `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env TFJS=tfjs"
  }
```

So in the file where I define my model I `require` TensorFlow like this:

```
const tf = require(`@tensorflow/${process.env.TFJS}`);
```

For the build file Webpack will substitute `@tensorflow/tfjs`. The neat thing is if we `require` this module directly in a node script we can access a different value for `process.env.TFJS`, passed via the command line. This is what I am doing:

```
TFJS=tfjs-node node my-script.js
```

So inside the script `process.env.TFJS` will be set to `tfjs-node`, which will be interpolated into the `require` call. It works! Neat.

The `scripts` section of my `package.json` now looks something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env TFJS=tfjs",
    "my-script": "TFJS=tfjs-node node my-script.js"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to sort of achieve what I want to do using npm [package aliasing](https://rhythmandbinary.com/post/2021-12-06-creating-aliases-with-npm), with multiple `package.json`s. Basically the idea is to install `tfjs` with an alias (say, tfjs), in the top-level `package.json`, as in:

```
npm install tfjs@npm:@tensorflow/tfjs
```

Then have a `scripts` subfolder with a second `package.json`, with just the following contents:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "tfjs": "npm:@tensorflow/tfjs-node@^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

Then `cd` into the `scripts` folder and execute `npm install`. This will create a new `node_modules` folder under scripts, with `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` aliased to `tfjs`.

It works... but I don't really like it as a solution. Mainly because of having to `npm install` a second time, to create a new `node_modules`.